# d3 loop over same item multiple times

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an array of objects in this format

```
var data = [
    {
        start: {
            row: 10,
            column: 10
        },
        end: {
            row: 11,
            column: 10
        }
    },
    {
        start: {
            row: 13,
            column: 10
        },
        end: {
            row: 15,
            column: 10
        }
    },
    ....

]
```

I am trying to create a svg path line using d3. Basically for each array item i would like to create atleast three points. Something like the line begins at `data[i].start` and then moves to another point dependent on `data[i].start and end` and finally ends at `data[i].end`

So i am doing something like this..

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d){return d;}).y(function(d){return d;})
svg.attr("d", line(data))
```

But this `line` allows me to go over `data[i]` only once.. so what would be the way so that i can go over the same array item multiple times.

Comment: You probably want a custom line generator for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should interpolate the data before passing it to the line function. 
Something like:

```
newData = data.map(function(d){
    line = [];
    start = {x:d.start.row,y:d.start.column}
    middle = {x:d.end.row-d.start.row,y:d.end.column-d.start.column} 
    end = {x:d.end.row,y:d.end.column}
    return [start,middle,end]
})
```

Now, you also need to update the line accessor to get the `x` and `y` attribute:

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d){return d.x;}).y(function(d){return d.y;})
```

Finally, draw the line:

```
svg.attr("d", line(newData))
```